# C# Cannot get DataSource of type casted Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, casting

I have a TabControl with tabpages, each with a datagridview that is generated at runtime and bound with a datasource again at runtime. This is the code to do so:

```
foreach (string cat in category)  //category is a list of categories I wish to make tabs for
{
    TabPage page = new TabPage(cat);
    DataGridView data = new DataGridView();
    data.Name = "Data";
    data.Location = new Point(1, 0);
    data.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    data.ReadOnly = true;
    data.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
    data.MultiSelect = false;

    //here load data for the datagridview
    try
    {
         using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Class1.connString))
         {
             string sql = "SELECT Code, `Problem Description` FROM problemcode WHERE Category = '" + cat + "' AND Type = 'Problem' ORDER BY `Problem Description`";

             connection.Open();
             using (MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
             {
                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                   MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                   da.Fill(dt);
                   data.DataSource = dt;
             }
             connection.Close();
         }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to load problem data.\n\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
   }

   //here I add the datagridview to the tab
   page.Controls.Add(data);
   this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);

   data.CellDoubleClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(data_CellDoubleClick);
   data.CellEnter += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(data_CellEnter);
```

}

For the sake of this discussion, I will just talk about the datagridview from one tab. I want to access this datagridview's datasource when I click on the tab, but since it is generated at runtime, I do it like so:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
DataGridView selectedDtgv = new DataGridView();

if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.ContainsKey("Data")) //find datagridview named "Data"
{
    selectedDtgv = (DataGridView)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["Data"];
    bs.DataSource = selectedDtgv.DataSource;
}
```

But I get no data within my BindSource bs object. If I do something like selectedDtgv.Rows.Count it gives me the correct count of rows, so why does it not give me the DataSource?

Comment: Can you clarify `foreach` is traversing on TabPages? Do you want to display `datagridview` generated at runtime for every tab page?

Comment: Well this is slightly simplified code, I already have the foreach creating a datagridview on each tab working perfectly. What I need is when clicking on one of those tabs, to get get the datagridview within that tab, and get it's datasource so I can bind it elsewhere. My issue is in the last block of code where it does not get the selectedDtgv.DataSource

Comment: I think simplified version of code is adding more confusion. You must have added datagridview control in TabPage's controls collection. You have to provide more information.

Comment: sharpstudent, sorry for my late response. I have updated my original post with my actual code, which shows me looping through a list of categories, and for each category I create a datagridview and bind it with data queried from a mysql database. Then I create a tab and add the datagrid to the tab. So my end result is a tabcontrol with many tabs, each with a datagridview with their own data. Now my issue is the bottom code chunk where when I click on a tab, I want to get the datasource from the specific datagridview on that tab, and bind it elsewhere. This is where I have the problem.

Comment: Apparently, there is no issue visible. BindingSource object should get the data of selected datagridview.

Comment: After further testing, I have found the issue which is actually unrelated. So the above code does indeed work fine.

Comment: OK. I will recommend using Command Parameters to avoid sql injections. Also there is no requirement to close the connection if you use `using` block.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will make the said changes. Thanks again for your attention throughout!